# Где ошибка в выделение памяти для строки? Почему в консоли лишние символы?

Tags: c, строки, память

[image: Ввод с клавиатуры сверху ,а снизу то что выдает программа. Почему лишние символы?]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *t, a, temp;
    int b = 0, n = 1, i = 0;

    t = malloc(n * sizeof(char));

    while (a != '\n')
    {
        scanf("%c", &a);
        if (a != '\n')
        {
            if (n == 1)
            {
                t[n - 1] = a;
            }
            else
            {
                t = (char*)realloc(t, n);
                t[n - 1] = a;
            }
            n++;
        }
    }
    printf(t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А нулевой символ вы случайно не забыли?...

Comment: А что нужно сделать? Просто я новичок в си.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте 5 строк.

```
    if (a != '\n')
    {
        // Все, как у вас
    }
    else
    {
        t = (char*)realloc(t, n);
        t[n - 1] = 0;
    }
```

Но вообще-то на каждый символ делать `realloc` — очень неэффективно...

Answer (score 0):

У вас изначально ошибка. Вы выделяете всего 1 байт. Нельзя залазить за пределы выдлеленной памяти.

```
int b = 0, n = 1, i = 0;
t = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
```

для начала добавьте ввод n или задайте изначально достаточным для строки

далее по последнему символу.
или см. предыдущий ответ, или после цикла

```
t[n-1] = 0; 
printf(t);
```

или в самом начале инициализировать ваш массив нулями

```
t = malloc(n * sizeof(char));
memset(t,'\0',n * sizeof(char));
```